# Rsync can view modules and retrieve files, but not send

Tags: centos, rsync, solaris

I am setting up rsync to synchronize files between two separated servers (A and B) in different networks, both running Solaris 10 OS. I am using --daemon.

Right now, I am able to get the module list of server B from server A, as well as downloading files from B to A. However when trying to upload files from A to B the process hangs.

Analysing the log files generated by rsync I can see that the connection between the servers is established but then lost.

Log file server A:

```
root# rsync -rltgD --progress testfile x.x.x.x::test/

building file list ...
1 file to consider
testfile
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: read error: Connection timed out (145)
rsync: error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(604) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Log file server B:

```
[4799] connect from UNKNOWN (x.x.x.x)
[4799] rsync to test/ from UNKNOWN (x.x.x.x)
[4799] receiving file list
[4657] rsync: read error: Connection timed out (145)
[4657] rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(604) [receiver=2.6.9]
[4657] rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(453) [generator=2.6.9]
```

Permissions in the destination (Server B) are defined as chmod 777.
Inetd is configured to allow rsync with anonymous access.
I tried changing paths and ownership so it would be equal in both servers, no luck. I also matched the versions to 2.6.9 as well as using Virtual Machines and Physical machines, the problem remains.
I also tried with different OS, namely CentOS and Windows 7 Professional. Using these rsync clients I can sync files with server B without any problem (these machines are in the same network as server B).
I captured the packets of a successful synchronization between server B and the CentOS 6.7 machine and compared them with a failed synchronization between server B and server A, I reached the same conclusion drawn from the log files: the TCP and rsync connections are established, but the files are not transfered.

Any help regarding this problem is deeply appreciated.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has this problem, I solved it with the MTU parameter. Since server B had ICMP protocol blocked, MTU value was automatically defined to 1500 bytes. When this value was changed to 1280 bytes on server A, the connection started working as it should.